Visual Studio 2022 doesn't indent multi-line method calls with default settings?
I'm new to Visual Studio, and trying to figure out the auto-formatter. Somehow, I seem to have run into a issue formatting some super basic code (it's C#):
        someObj.someMethodCall(
param1
param2
param3
... (more params)
);

I would expect the auto formatter to do this:
        someObj.someMethodCall(
            param1
            param2
            param3
            ... (more params)
        );

But instead it does.... nothing? I tried invoking the formatter manually (and it was formatting other lines, so I know it ran), looked through settings, tried to find others online with the same issue, but so far I still have no idea why it's not working.

How do you produce first snippet? Is it copy/pasted? Did you invoke formatting function? And it does nothing? I expect auto-indent as you type the code and hit enter-key to appear, but there is none.

When you break apart parameter lists and array/collection initializers, auto-format doesn't work well. Select the lines you want to indent and press TAB. To un-indent press SHIFT-TAB.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes: "doesn't work well". Let me rephrase: "Doesn't work at all" VS simply gives up.

Wow really? VS doesn't support auto-formatting for parameter lists when they are broken apart by line returns? That's crazy! Well, at least that means there's nothing wrong with my VS setup at least... (other than the lack of a super basic indenting feature )

There is option of indentation manually.
Click on the parameter and there is a light bulb on the left -> Warp every argument

By the way, if you enter text manually, Visual Studio will automatically format it.
    someObj.someMethodCall(
           param1


  );


Kind of crazy that there's no way to set up the "Format document" operation to do this for me! But, nice to know that there is a way to do this.
It would be much better if there was a keyboard shortcut though... But I'm guessing there isn't?
Also, as a side note, it's a screwdriver on my system, not a lightbulb. (probably due to something else on the line of code)
